# Exporting whole docker container for jenkins or just volume?

Tags: docker, jenkins

#### Create jenkins container and bind volume - jenkins-data

`docker run --name myJenkins1 -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts`

#### make changes - update plugins, run builds etc

login to jenkins in browser etc

#### now export the whole container as a tar

`docker export 2c8b996d3088 > jenkinsContainerAndVolume.tar`

Since this includes the jenkins image, it seems quite large. I am going to need the jenkins image anyway, but wondered if there is a better practice or standard to save just the volume data?

Answer (score 0):

The `docker-export` command doesn't save the container's volumes.

To backup the named volume you could use tar like this:

```
docker run -v jenkins-data:/dbdata -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar zcvf /backup/backup.tar.gz /dbdata
```

In case you need to migrate this container with all its volumes to another host I use this script:

https://github.com/ricardobranco777/docker-volumes.sh

Comment: Thankyou very much for your response. I think I tried something similar before but get errors. - docker: Error response from daemon: create $(pwd): "$(pwd)" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.

Comment: What is the output of pwd?

Comment: it is: C:\Users\steve

Comment: It is because your path contains a ":". Try with `--mount type=volume,source=$(pwd),destination=/backup` instead of `-v $(pwd):/backup`.

Comment: docker run -v jenkins-data:/dbdata --mount type=volume,source=$(pwd),destination=/backup ubuntu tar zcvf /backup/backup.tar.gz /dbdata - gives me error = docker: Error response from daemon: create $(pwd): "$(pwd)" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed.

Comment: I should add I'm using windows 10